# Calling "return render" won't work when calling from an outside method (Django, views.py)

Tags: python, django

Very first question here.

I am having trouble creating a reusable method to use in my views.py file for handling user authentication. I have created and imported a utils.py file that looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def check_log_in(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        if user.is_staff == False:
            message = "You are not an authorized staff member."
            form = AuthenticationForm()
            context = {'form': form,
                       'message': message}
            return render(request, 'obits/login.html', context)
    else:
        message = "Please log-in to add a new record."
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        context = {'form': form,
                   'message': message}
        return render(request, 'obits/login.html', context)
```

If I put this same code directly into my view, it works just fine, but now that I have it as a separate method, it doesn't break at the return render and instead continues on through the code. I used print statements to test that it was calling correctly and it is. Here is the current view:

```
def new(request):
    check_log_in(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            #code, yada, yada, context
            return render(request, 'obits/detail.html', context)
        else:
            #code, yada, yada, context
            return render(request, 'obits/new.html', context)
    else:
        #code, yada, yada, context
        return render(request, 'obits/new.html', context)
```

In this current set-up, it will detect that the user is not logged-in, but still just go right ahead and display the new.html page, rather than redirecting to log-in. But if I cut and paste the exact code contained in check_log_in instead of just calling it, it works fine.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Jieter's answer is correct, but note this isn't really a good way of doing things. Django has a `login_required` decorator which you should use; if the user is not logged in, they are redirected to a separate view which takes care of displaying and validating the login form. That is a much better pattern.

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required` and right above your view method `@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return from `check_log_in()` but do nothing with the returned value, execution of your `new()` view is going to continue.

You need to check if `check_log_in()` returned something and if it did, return that from your `new()` view:

```
def new(request):
    response = check_log_in(request)
    if response is not None:
        return response

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # rest of your code
```